# Capture all opportunity fields & send to PHP script

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I am building an app that lets our sales team (who uses Salesforce) export to a new Evernote note with one click. I have the Evernote functionality already available in a PHP script I wrote, and I was planning on using Javascript to make an XHR to that script, but that is irrelevant at this point.

What I need to be able to do is capture all of the fields in the currently-open opportunity and upon clicking my custom button / link, capture all those fields as a javascript variable that I can then POST to my PHP app. Even a simple example of how I could go about capturing one field would be great -- I can't seem to find anything in the SalesForce documentation that covers this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is an Apex callout.  [This doc on developer.force.com](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts) covers it OK, it's a starting point anyway (although it doesn't show you how to query for the fields of Opportunity -- you'll find that in the regular Apex docs under SOQL).  For some sample code you might look at the [Force.com Toolkit for Google APIs](http://wiki.apexdevnet.com/page/Google_Data_API_Toolkit), which uses callouts pretty extensively (although you may need to wade through it a bit to find the relevant parts).

In any case, if you start by searching the docs on Apex callouts, that will probably get you rolling in the right direction.

Another method of doing this, incidentally, would be to wire up a custom button with the [AJAX toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/) to compose the body of the post, and then post it and have your PHP page redirect the user back to where he started.  That could work too, although my first inclination would be to do it in Apex instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do they really have to click a button? What if meeting some condition would work?

I'm asking because Workflow rules (which are usually good for field updates, creation of Tasks or sending emails) have option to send out a SOAP message. It'd be a somewhat bloated XML but on the plus side - no coding needed, pure configuration. Plus - their delivery status can be tracked easily.

Check the [help](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm) and at the very least you now have the keyword to Google for ;) [Topic on consuming them on salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/how-do-i-consume-workflow-outbound-messages) might also be useful.

If it has to be under a button - you probably could do with making a fake update of some helper field... Maybe even "count of messages sent"?